# Passing a button with id with jQuery .html() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to replace a divs content with jQuery's .html() function and within that new content i want to create a button, containing an ID that i can access from another function.

```
$('#content').html("<div style='padding: 10px;'>"
       + " <input class='btn btn-primary' value='Button' id='button'> </input>"
       +   "</div>");
```

After this i got another function that tries to access the button:

```
$('#button').click(function(e){
    //... do something
});
```

I inspected the generated button in Chrome and it tells me that it has the right ID but somehow nothing happens when i try to trigger it?

Any solutions on that? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$('#content').on('click', '#button', function(e){
    //... do something
})`

Comment: Don't know the whole code, but if i remove `});` from your first code example everything works fine.

Comment: Your code worked, thanks! @Sebastian sorry i added these on accident.